# Error en gráficas semanales en python

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib

¿Habría alguna forma de en una gráfica semanala, para cada dá meter muchos parametros y sus valores con matplot? es que me da error ya que el eje x no tiene la misma longitud que el eje y

Este sería el código, pero el mismo dia me lo repite mas veces

```
json_output = {}

for obj in objs:
    json_output.update(fillJsonOutputWeek(obj))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 5))
formato = dates.DateFormatter("%Y-%m-%d")
i = 0
j = 0
colors = ["Purple", "Fuchsia", "Navy", "Blue", "Teal", "Aqua", "Green", "Lime", "Olive", "Yellow", "Maroon", "Red", "Black", "Gray", "Silver", "Salmon", "DarkGreen", "FireBrick", "Orange", "MidnightBlue"]

for key, value in json_output.items():
    datos = {"day": [], "name": [], "values": []}


    for key1, value1 in value.items():
        average = 0
        values = 0
        for index, v in enumerate(value1):
            average += float(v)

        values = average/288
        datos["day"].append(key)
        datos["name"].append(key1)
        datos["values"].append(values)

        if i == 0:
            plt.plot(datos["day"], datos["values"], marker = "o", markersize = 3, color = colors[j], label=key1)
            j += 1
        else:
            plt.plot(datos["day"], datos["values"], marker = "o", markersize = 3, color = colors[j])
    i += 1
```

Comment: ¿Pues publicar lo que has hecho?

Comment: Ya está editado el comentario, faltaria mas código pero ya es configuración de la gráfica y guardarla